# Push Notification sound stops when the notification badge disappears

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I need to play notification sound for a long time (20-25 sec) when the app is in background. I have imported my custom sound file (25 sec in duration) in the project. Custom sound is playing but the problem is it only plays as long as the notification badge remains on the screen, i.e. 3-4 sec. As soon as the badge disappears, the notification sound also stops. What should I do ?

Answer (score -1):

In this link [Managing Your App’s Notification Support](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SupportingNotificationsinYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH4-SW10), go to section title `Preparing Custom Alert Sounds`

It mentions, `Custom sounds must be under 30 seconds when played. If a custom sound is over that limit, the default system sound is played instead.`

Possible duplicate of [Limits on iPhone push notification sounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463599/limits-on-iphone-push-notification-sounds)

Comment: The question the author is asking is different. It makes sense, he already have sound less than 30 seconds duration.